# An unhandled exception of type SeleniumWebDriverException occurred in WebDriverdll A exception with a null response was thrown using EdgeDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver

I am using Selenium in C# with the Edge driver however when I run the code I receive the following error.
    Using OpenQA.Selenium;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;

```
class HomePageTests
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        {
            {
                IWebDriver AzimaHome = new EdgeDriver();
                AzimaHome.Navigate().GoToUrl("http:www.msn.com");

                IList<IWebElement> terms = AzimaHome.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));
                terms.First(element => element.Text == "").Click();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Exception thrown:

```
OpenQA SeleniumWebDriverException' in WebDriver.dll
An unhandled exception of type SeleniumWebDriverException' occurred in WebDriverdll
A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:52586/session. The status of the exception was Receive Failure, and the message was: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
```

By the way this is in Visual Studio 2019:

```
_05.NoSuchElementException.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: _05.NoSuchElementException.exe): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\Private Assemblies\Runtime\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The program '[17312] _05.NoSuchElementException.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
OpenQA SeleniumWebDriverException' in WebDriver.dll
An unhandled exception of type SeleniumWebDriverException' occurred in WebDriverdll
A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:52586/session. The status of the exception was Receive Failure, and the message was: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
```

...implies that the *EdgeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new **Browsing Context** i.e. *Microsoft Edge Browser* session.

Some more details about your **Microsoft Edge** and **Microsoft EdgeHTML** would have helped us to debug the issue in a better way. However, incase you are using **`EdgeHTML 18`** or **`EdgeHTML 19`**, as per the documentation in [Microsoft WebDriver](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/):

> Microsoft WebDriver for Microsoft Edge (EdgeHTML) versions 18 and 19 is a Windows Feature on Demand which ensures that it’s always up to date automatically and enables some new ways to get Microsoft WebDriver.

---

### Steps

To configure you will have to enable Developer Mode:

```
Go to Settings > Update and Security > For Developer and then select "Developer mode".
```

To install run **Microsoft Edge version 18** through an elevated command prompt:

```
DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver~~~~0.0.1.0
```

---

### tl; dr

As per [Microsoft Edge Developer Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide):

> EdgeHTML 18 includes the following new and updated features shipped in the current release of the Microsoft Edge platform, as of the [Windows 10 October 2018 Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/whats-new/windows-10-build-17763) (10/2018, Build 17763). For changes in specific [Windows Insider](https://insider.windows.com/en-us/) Preview builds, see the [Microsoft Edge Changelog](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/changelog/) and [What's New in EdgeHTML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide/whats-new).

Comment: I have completed all of these above suggestions and I am still receiving the same error message as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

The most of your code is right except the last line. I modified it and tested with the following code and it can work well:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;

public class webdriver
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {    
        IWebDriver AzimaHome = new EdgeDriver();
        AzimaHome.Navigate().GoToUrl("http:www.msn.com");

        IList<IWebElement> terms = AzimaHome.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));
        terms.First(element => element.Text == "msn").Click();
    }
}
```

I think the error occurs mainly because the Microsoft WebDriver version you're using doesn't match the Microsoft Edge version you're using.

If you're using Microsoft Edge version **prior to 18**, you can download the appropriate webdriver for your installed version of Microsoft Edge in [this link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/#downloads). If your Microsoft Edge version is **18 or higher**, you can install the appropriate webdriver version according to the ways in [this article](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2018/06/14/webdriver-w3c-recommendation-feature-on-demand/#Rg8g2hRfjBQQVRXy.97).

Comment: Pretty close enough ;)